# Closest equivelant to TexShop on Windows or Linux?

Tags: windows, editors, texshop, linux

Just finishing up my thesis which I've created in TexShop in osx. I'd like to allow others to edit my document. I've got a desktop that's got Windows and Ubuntu installed that they could do this on (they'll be latex newbies).

My main concern is that TexShop has the feature of having a master document, with sub documents able to be compiled with a special comment line (that directs the compiler back to the main document). Are there any other editors that also support this feature?

Main question: what editor do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest TeXstudio. It can work with master documents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: TeXworks draws its main inspiration from TeXShop and is able to deal with master documents and subdocuments.

Comment: TeXMaker and TeXnic Center also can manage projects.

Comment: When I switched to GNU/Linux and needed to replace TeXShop, I ended up using Kile. I tried the editors which were meant to be more similar but didn't like them. In general, though, I am not sure it is possible to answer your question except by advising you to try some and see. (Part of the problem is that you may not know yourself which feature you cannot live without and which you can.)

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I also found the 'big list' 
(http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) 

It seems the feature I'm referring to is % !TeX directive. Which all of your suggestions support :) 

Onwards!!